# Вывод нескольких изображений из sql

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте, подскажите в каком виде лучше записывать названия изображений в БД. На данный момент знаю только как 1 изображение добавить, а желательно бы около 20.

Думал добавить в таком виде и при выводе раскидывать через explode, но не совсем получается такой вариант.

```
$str = "1.jpg-2jpg-3jpg-4jpg-";
$expl = explode('-', $str);
$count = substr_count($str, '-');

echo $expl[0];
```

Comment: 1 изображение = 1 запись в БД

Comment: @DaemonHK так не удобно будет. Потому-что изображений  много и полей слишком много создавать придется. Хочу в одно поле все изображения

Comment: ChipaChop Нет, вы не поняли, @DaemonHK имел ввиду, создать в БД отдельную таблицу, в которой только 3 поля: id, id-сущности, название. где id-сущности это id той записи в той таблице куда вы сейчас хотели положить изображения. если у нас 20 изображений - то создается 20 отдельных записей. в таком виде в SQL наиболее удобно с ними работать. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: @Mike хм, точно, как я сразу не додумался :D Спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно добавить названия изображений, а вернее ссылки на них, то можно использовать, формат типа csv, или json, оба они текстовые, и их можно разобрать в цикле. как при записи в базу так и для вызова из нее.
Сначала подготовьте, потом запишите.